# Outlook2013 SocialConnector can't add facebook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

For two days I've been getting the message
**sorry we're having server problems, so we can't add facebook right now.**
I was able to add twitter and linkedin.
Is this a connector problem in OUTLOOK2013? 
Is this a known issue? 
Is there a solution ?

[image: add service to account dialog]

[image: The error]

EDIT: **After hunting around some more I found an interesting and useful alternative**
In Outlook 2013 menu option
File==>Account Settings

[image]

I WAS able to enter my LinkedIn User and password as well as FaceBook user and Password.
Now pictures do appear in Emails. So the real estate is at least used now :-)

Comment: I would like to invite you to reformulate your question and answer. In this form, it is not entirely clear what your issue is/was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IM marking this as answered since, the reduce screen realestate wastage option isnt possible but at least use can get the content set properly.   See EDIT and screen shots